# How to get a blank line after cin

Tags: c++

I need a line to separate the users inputs from the results. This is for a basic computer science course.

```
cout << "Please enter (variable): ";
cin >> (variable);
cout << "\n\n:";
cout << "(results)" << endl;
```

Is there any other way to get the blank line after the cin, or is this viable code?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `endl` rather than the `\n` if you want, but what you have is fine.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is ok. However, this is another, more compact and legible option:

```
out << "Please enter (variable): ";
cin >> (variable);
cout << endl << "(results)" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is old and answered, but the given answers have some pitfalls according to the official [GNU documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/streambufs.html).

`endl` is mistakenly used for newline by many coders, which is not what it is made for, and using it for this purpose renders it less efficient for it's true use case. It is used for flushing the buffers, using it very often for just newlines would make you prone to use it while you are writing text/data in a file and that use would be effecting it's buffering efficiency.
Morever flushing buffer each time you need a newline is not a desireable thing.

So how can you add new-line whenever you use `cin`

### If variable is string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string var;
cout << "Please enter (variable):\n";
getline(cin, var);
cout << "(results)" << var << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

### If variable is not string

```
cout << "Please enter (variable):\n";
cin >> (variable);
cout << "\n(results)\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int a, b;
cout << "Give 'a' a value: ";
cin >> a;
cout << "" << endl;
cout << "Give 'b' a value: ";
cin >> b;
cout << "" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).